# Load data from file into specific mysql partition

Tags: mysql

Every hour, my system generates a `.tsv` file to highlight which directories were accessed in the past hour. The file has ~100,000 lines in the following format:

```
dirName    parentDirHashcode    dirHashcode    numAccesses
```

I've been trying to programmatically load these files into a mysql table, but I want to add some extra data to the table - a date column representing the date (e.g. `20150730`) and an hour column representing the hour (e.g. `21`).

In `Apache Hive`, this can be done by partitioning the table (by date and then by hour) - is there a way to do this in `mysql`?

I tried `load data local infile 'file.tsv' into table newTable, date=20150730, hour=21` but it didn't work :(

If it helps, the schema of `newTable` is `(dirName varchar(1024), parentHash int, hash int, accesses bigint, date int, hour int)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify whatever extra fields you want:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ...
INTO table newTable (dirname, parenthash, hash, ...)
SET date=curdate(), hour=hour(now())
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @marc-b's answer, I ended up doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable (dirname VARCHAR(1024), parentHash INT, hash INT, accesses BIGINT, date INT, hour INT)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (hour)
    SUBPARTITION BY HASH (date)
    SUBPARTITIONS 31 (
        PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
        PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (12),
        PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (18),
        PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
    );

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.tsv' INTO TABLE newTable (dirName, parentHash, hash, accesses)
    SET date=20150730, hour=12;
```

Worked like a charm.